# Django collectstatic giving ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: django

When running the command collectstatic I get the following error:

**ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack**

This had started to happened since I added the line below to my static finder. Can anyone help? I need the common folder to be found.

**settings.py**

```
# Used to provide absolute paths. Normally the default is fine.
LOCAL_PATH = normpath(join(dirname(__file__), '..'))

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    LOCAL_PATH + '/public/common/',
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong setting.

You want to do what you're doing in STATICFILES_DIRS.

STATICFILES_FINDERS specifies python modules which will search for a file. 
STATICFILES_DIRS specifies which paths `django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder` should look in.

So:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

STATICFILES_DIRS = ('%s/public/common/' % LOCAL_PATH,)
```

Comment: Django's myriad of settings confuses even veterans ;)